# Javascript: Simple Particle Motion, Particle Elastically Bouncing Off Other Particle

Tags: javascript, particle-system

I've created this rather simple javascript; balls or 'molecules' moving around the screen. I was hoping to add to the functionality that when one ball comes into contact with another, they swap velocities. We don't need to worry about any angles, just when they come into contact with each other, the velocities swap. (Instead of changing the velocities though, in the code linked I've just coded a colour change)

I've  been trying to call the function 'someplace' to recognise when the molecules touch, but I've had no luck with that. I don't really understand why.

Link to code:

http://jsbin.com/arokuz/5/

There seems to be three main problems:

- The molecules seem to be randomly changing, rather than when two molecules touch.
- When one sets the array to have say, 3 molecules, only two appear, the first is actually there, but unresponsive to .fillstyle changes, so invisible against the canvas
- With the function method I would only be able to recognise when molecules in series (1 and 2 or 4 and 5) in the array touch...how could I check all the molecules?

Comment: You may want to look into quad-tree collision detection with many items on the screen at once, moving so quickly: http://gamedev.tutsplus.com/tutorials/implementation/quick-tip-use-quadtrees-to-detect-likely-collisions-in-2d-space/

Comment: @eterps : did you actually try this way of solving collision ? This article suggest a way that is not suited for javascript -too much recursion, too much garbage created-, and does mentions quite some 'details' that would just... make it work. Unless with very specific needs, a simple spacial hash will perform much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only comparing a molecule with 2 other ones, which in fact might be anywhere.
Collision detection is a topic quite hard to solve, but if you want to have your idea 
working quickly you might go for a n^2 algorithm with 2 nested for loops.

the code is quite expected :

```
  // collision
  for(var t = 0; t < molecules.length-1; t++)
     for(var tt = t+1; tt < molecules.length; tt++) {
         var p1 = molecules[t];
         var p2 = molecules[tt];
         if (sq(p1.x-p2.x) +sq(p1.y-p2.y) < sq(p1.radius+p2.radius) ) 
          {
            p1.collided = 8;  // will diplay for next 8 frames
            p2.collided = 8;  // .
         }
  }
```

the fiddle is here :
http://jsbin.com/arokuz/10

Answer (score 0):

The reason only two appear when three are made isn't because the first one doesn't render it is rather the last one doesn't, this is because of how you draw them by comparing its distance with the next one in the list - as it is the last there is no next and thus throws a null error and continues (check the console).

The reason why they seem to "randomly" detect collisions or not is because they are not checking against all other molecules - only the next in the list, unfortunately the only simply way to do it would be to go through all other balls for every ball and checking.

To get the molecules to detect distance you could use the pythagorean theorem, I typically use it such as:

```
var distx = Math.abs(molecule1.x - molecule2.x);
var disty = Math.abs(molecule1.x - molecule2.y);
var mindist = molecule1.radius + molecule2.radius;
return Math.sqrt(distx*distx+disty*disty) < mindist;
```

Comment: comparing the squared distance to the square min distance will trade a sqrt for a sq : return (distx*distx + disty*disty) < mindist*mindist